# Magento backup folder

Tags: magento, backup

i've this strange behaviour on my magento installation: every time i try to launch a backup, the file is saved into *var* folder instead of *var/backups* folder, so that is not visible into backups list (whose looking for *var/backups* folder).

Any suggestion? Nothing has been changed since yesterday.

Thanks

Comment: make sure the user which magento operates as on the server has permission to create files inside the backup folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/**
     * Get directory path where backups stored
     *
     * @return string
     */

```
  public function getBackupsDir()
    {
        return Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'backups';
    }
```

is the function in class Mage_Backup_Helper_Data.

You need to log value of whats returned by this function by changing code to

```
 public function getBackupsDir()
    {
        $result= Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'backups';
        Mage::log($result);
        return $result;
    }
```